# Why does GetSafeHwnd() return zero in an ActiveX control?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc, activex

I have developed a MFC Activex control which is windowless and invisible in runtime, while i assumed that basically an activex is a control that would manipulate a windows handle, i have used `GetSafeHwnd()` to get windows handle, but unfortunately this method returns zero when it runs. maybe i had set wrong option when creating my activex. how i can create a windowless activex which could manipulate windows hanlde?

Comment: A windowless control by definition doesn't have a window. Do you want a message-only window?

Comment: i want to map a user defiened message to my app.

Comment: Can you show code that creates the window?

Comment: my activex control doesn't have the window

Comment: I'm no expert on MFC or ActiveX, but you seem to be asking why a control that has no window has now window. I imagine that you need to create a window.

Comment: so if a windowless control could not has a handle how windows could pass a messages to the control?

Comment: Create a windowed control but make that window a message only window. Or get your control to create a message only `CWnd`. Make sure you have a message pump on the thread that creates the window.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/3551/discussion-between-m-abdi-and-david-heffernan)

Answer (score 2):

By definition, windowless ActiveX control doesn't have a window, and rendered as part of its parent. If you want to work with Windows messages in the control, you can create worker thread with a message loop, and handle any messages there. To have message loop, you don't need a window, just thread. This solution can be implemented in windowless control or in any COM component.

Alternatively, you can use windowed ActiveX control by changing its properties.

Comment: but my activex uses a SDK which it needs a handle to generate a user defined message. i tried to use the parent handle as input parameter and passed it to that SDK but my control doesn't received the generated message by the SDK

Comment: @m-abdi You need a window. You don't appear to have one. Make one! We can't guess at your code. Don't make us struggle to help you in this way.

Comment: If you need a window handle, and your ActiveX control must be windowless, create invisible window for handling these messages, as suggested by David Heffernan.