# the function CWnd::CreateControl succeeds, but m_hWnd is NULL

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, mfc

I run the code with VC++ 6.0, everything is OK. But when run the same code under Visual C++ 2010, the handle of `wnd`(namely `m_hWnd`) is always NULL. Besides, the return value bRet is TRUE (i.e. success).

Here is my code:

```
BOOL CDemoDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();

    // Set the icon for this dialog.  The framework does this automatically
    //  when the application's main window is not a dialog
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, TRUE);         // Set big icon
    SetIcon(m_hIcon, FALSE);        // Set small icon

    // TODO: Add extra initialization here
    CRect rect;
    GetClientRect(rect);
    CWnd wnd;
    BOOL bRet = wnd.CreateControl(_T("WMPlayer.OCX"), NULL, WS_VISIBLE, rect, this, 19089);

    return TRUE;  // return TRUE  unless you set the focus to a control
}
```

Comment: Did you try to step into `CreateControl` with the debugger to see what happens?

Comment: Does it work? Actually OCX can be windowless (so m_hWnd will **always** be NULL).

Comment: @Tri also [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7956520/492336)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wnd object is going out of scope - try making it a member and checking what happens then. Also, if you are trying to assign a different handle to your dialog m_hWnd object, then you are making a mistake, since the m_hWnd should be valid for your dialog by the time that OnInitDialog is called (in response to the Create call), so you should not be reassigning the dialogs member window handle, but rather creating a separate member for it. Hope this helps.